# Does AWS ALB pass through, alter, or drop the x-b3-traceID?

Tags: amazon-web-services, networking, istio, aws-application-load-balancer

**Scenario**

- I have an AWS ALB that routes like this:
  `ALB > Ingress > Istio ingress-gateway > all-the-things`
- I am seeing the `x-b3-traceid` in the ALB access logs, and in the WAF logs, as what I expect it to be, coming in from an outside request.
- I then see a totally different `x-b3-traceid` show up in the Envoy access-logs. I want the one I send in, but I see something different. It's breaking tracing for us.
- I've used a custom header (something like `x-sanity-check`) and seen that all the way through the system, so I know the ALB passes through some headers.

**Thoughts**
Honestly, this one is pretty simple. I have read AWS docs for a couple days now, and cannot find a straight answer, so asking here at long last. And please don't ask me to use the `x-amzn-id` header. I've already read about that one.

**Question**
I honestly just want to know, and see somewhere in the documentation, if the AWS ALB does or does not pass through the `x-b3-traceid` header. Does it rewrite it, or drop it altogther (in which case, I know Istio would supply one when it sees that it is missing)? Does anyone have any insight into how the AWS ALB may be intercepting/altering/dropping the `x-b3-traceid` header?